# Selector CSS al pulsar sobre algo

Tags: css, html5

Tengo este selector "hover" que realiza una accion al tener el raton encima. Pero no se como puedo hacer que la accion se desencadene al ser pulsado. Algo similar como al onClick() pero en CSS

```
.flip:hover {
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-180deg) translateX(100%);
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué tipo de elemento quieres que afecte ese click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba con :active

.flip:active {
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-180deg) translateX(100%);
}

```css
a:active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">w3schools.com</a>
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">wikipedia.org</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The :active selector styles the active link.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra respuesta también valida es simular un click con un checkbox. Y controlar en css el evento **checked**.

[Te dejo un ejemplo realizado en codepen.](https://codepen.io/facundofernandez/pen/EbQwRN)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.flip {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.flip .flip-body {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0;
          transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#btnControl {
  display: none;
}
#btnControl:checked + label {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip">
  <input type="checkbox" id="btnControl"/>
  <label class="flip-body" for="btnControl">click</label>
  Soy el interior del div
</div>
```

Saludos.